# How do I redirect away from the login page, if the user is already logged in and goes to login page in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm using built in authentication system of Django 2.1.

URL file paths in urls.py file.

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('',include('rmcapp.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
      ]
```

Login.html path = " templates/registration/login.html
Using

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

as form tag in login.html file.

I haven't extended LoginView class in views.py file (If it is necessary then i'll extend)

I tried this in urls.py file

```
url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True)),
```

but it didn't worked.

Example Case:
User logs in by providing his credentials, once he is directed to the home page and presses browser's back button he'll land in the login page again. It'll again ask for the credentials but actually the user is already logged in. How do we redirect the user to the home page in this case?

Comment: check in first request.user.is_authenticated if true then redirect to index page else return login page

Comment: You're not showing us your login view or telling us where you get the login view from.

Comment: I'm sorry for incomplete information i've edited my question, i hope it clarifies my query.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) provided by Django, you'll see that it accepts a parameter, `redirect_authenticated_user`, that allows you to tell the login view to redirect if the user is already logged in.

However, this behavior is not really secure (as explained in the warning). And it's not really necessary. It's quite normal for a website to just display the login form even if a user is already logged in when explicitly going to that page.

What you probably want, is that your login view redirects to the **page the user requested before asked to login** rather than the home page (so the user doesn't have to go back).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I agree with what you said in the last paragraph. But if I want to redirect the logged in user whats the approach i should take. Thank you.

Comment: I explained that in the first paragraph